# Java Project SQL Server Update Query Not Updating Table, No Errors

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jsp, sql-injection

I'm working on a Java project that interacts with a SQL Server database. I'm trying to perform an update operation on a table using a SQL update query, but it doesn't seem to update the table, and I'm not receiving any error messages.

Here's a simplified version of my Java code:

```
// Database connection and query execution code
String id = request.getParameter("id");
try {
    Connection connect1 = ConnectionProvider.getCon();
    Statement ps = connect1.createStatement();
    ps.executeUpdate("update bloodreq set status='completed' where id='" + id + "'");
    response.sendRedirect("Requests.jsp?msg=deleted");
} catch (Exception e) {
    response.sendRedirect("Requests.jsp?msg=invalid");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

- Checked the SQL query for correctness.
- Ensured that the id parameter contains the expected value.
- Reviewed the SQL Server logs for any errors or issues related to the query.

Despite these efforts, I can't identify why the update query is not working. What steps should I take to diagnose and resolve this problem? Are there any common pitfalls I should be aware of when performing SQL Server updates in a Java project?

Comment: Have tried to run the update in SQL console? Does it work? Is id really characters and not numeric? Try without enclosing the id with `

Comment: it's probably not a good idea to write sql by getting it from request parameter. Read about sql injections and bobby tables.